# Get model component value from VueJS JSON Schema

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, jsonschema

I'm have a project in vuejs, Vuetify and the following library to generate forms dynamically using annotated JSON Schemas:
https://koumoul-dev.github.io/vuetify-jsonschema-form/latest/about

The library is great and do exactly what I need, generate form from JSON scheme, I can even add my own component, and show it on a form, the only missing thing is I cant get the slot component data into the model.

**you can find my example here:**
https://codepen.io/eran-levi/pen/jOqjroa

This is how I added the component:

```
<template slot="rating" slot-scope="{key, value, update, schema }" class="field">
      <star-rating :value="value" @rating-selected="update($event, key)" :show-rating="false" />
    </template>
```

and in the Schema JSON:

```
rating: {
      type: "number",
            title: "Rating",
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 5
        }
```

as you can see, once you hit the "Show Data" button, you can see the results of each field you edit, beside the value of the new star component I have added..

what am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your `update` method.

I added the `updateRating` method and bound it to the `@rating-selected` event.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9pjdxht6/1/

**vue-star-rating component:**

```
<star-rating :value="value" @rating-selected="updateRating" :show-rating="false" />
```

**updateRating method:**

```
updateRating: function(rating){
    this.model.rating = rating;
}
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! its working now, after digging I have found that this is working too:

<template slot="rating" slot-scope="{ value, on }" class="field">
  <star-rating :value="value" @rating-selected="on.input" :show-rating="false" />
</template>

I’ve removed update as that doesn’t seem to exist and used on.input instead.